# Modify request payload for Core API requests

Tags: rest-api, core-modifications, request-filter

i need to somehow add language to payload of the request made during template save in Site Editor. Is there some filter or action, so wordpress adds some data during request?

```
Request URL:
https://site.test/wp-json/wp/v2/template-parts/mytheme//header?_locale=user
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
127.0.0.1:443
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin



{"id":"mytheme//header","content":"<div style=\"background-color: #BE4C4C; height:3px;\">\r\n</div>\n\n<!-- wp:mytheme/header -->\n<!-- wp:mytheme/header-left {\"id\":13,\"url\":\"https://site.test/app/uploads/2024/01/photo.jpg\"} /-->\n\n<!-- wp:mytheme/header-right -->\n<!-- wp:navigation {\"ref\":220} /-->\n<!-- /wp:mytheme/header-right -->\n<!-- /wp:mytheme/header -->"}
```